# K-Clan detection based on a given connected Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

I have the following definition of the K-Clan:
A k-clan is a k-clique where the diameter of the corresponding sub-graph is at most k.

and here according to the graph bellow I do not know why 135 is not 2-Clan, but they are still 2-Clique,, I am wonderful if it is also 2-Clan since still satisfies the condition/definition of K-Clan !? the same 246 why not 2-Clan ?

Any suggestion please..
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by clique? and diameter of a clique?  I've always heard/used a clique to mean a complete subgraph... so the diameter is always 1.

Comment: see http://www.analytictech.com/networks/subgroup.htm

Comment: You'll probably want to put that definition in your question.  Most people, when they see $k$-clique will think you mean a clique on $k$ vertices (or a complete subgraph on $k$ vertices).

Comment: @TravisJ:
Please take care it is not my definition: see:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Clique.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply it was your definition... just the definition that is being used in the question.

Comment: so what is the best , which make more sense K or N, because I found in many web-sites using both (K and N) for same topic as I send you the link above where they use k-clique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

135 is not a $2$-clan because the induced subgraph on 135 does not have diameter at most 2 (it is not connected, so the diameter is infinite).  135 forms a 2-clique because it is a set in the graph where the pairwise distances between the points is at most 2.  $k$-clique looks at sets inside the whole graph.  $k$-clan looks at induced subgraphs.

Comment: but it should be the same issue in case 2-clique: because also the diameter here is infinite- nevertheless is still 2-clique ? or what you think please?

Comment: I think you are not completely true:
see 
k-clique is a maximal set of vertices that are at a distance no greater
than k from each other.
it is not infinite as you said in the answer !?

Comment: @user253008, what I said was 135 is not a $2$-clan because when you take the induced subgraph on 135 the graph is not connected so the diameter is infinite (not smaller than 2 as would be necessary to be a $2$-clan).

Comment: OK, I think you are right, so then the 2-clique does not look at the set of the point like (2-clan), but instead it looks at the whole connected graph ? that what you mean, if so, then I will close the question and select your answer to be the best one !?

Comment: @user253008, yes.  The $k$-clique looks at a set inside the whole graph (and distances between points in the entire graph).  The $k$-clan looks at distances in the induced subgraph.

Comment: I have selected your answer to be the best, could you rate my question ?